# Paper run out in esc/pos printer

Tags: php, printing, cakephp-2.0, escpos

I'm making system to print ticket using esc/pos printer
the problem is when the paper almost run out the printer just print some of it
and when I insert new paper the printer just continue to print the the rest of the ticket, so the ticket is now printed in 2 papers

how to tell the printer to start printing from the beginning when the paper run out?

I'm using mike42/escpos-php to print the ticket

[the ticket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1GGk.jpg)

[the ticket when paper run out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYtwP.jpg)

Pic show below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no such command in ESC/POS printers available.  You must detect the paper out condition in your software (ESC/POS commands do exist for this) and then reprint the whole ticket.

Comment: yes, the problem is how to detect when the paper run out

Comment: There are ESC/POS commands to query the status, check your technical reference guide of your specific printer model.  With some printers you can also configure a mode where it continously reports the status or status changes.  You software must then be able to receive such status reports, so polling might be easier as a first step.